# Database design for Multi tenant application

Tags: sql-server, database-design, multi-tenant

for a multi tenant app, we have the following database design:
[image]

which is based on shared database approach. Since we are identifying the tenants using company id (each company has a different set of employees and their tasks and so on), my question is

> Do we need a companyId key in the Task table also so that every record
>   of task can be clearly identified using the companyId OR we should
>   always use a Join?

because if we use the companyId in Task that would not be a properly normalized database as the Task is would relate to a company and an employee which is also related to the company.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of opinion. My take is to make companyId as a part of primary key and hence a mandatory field in every table.

In a multi tenant application, we should ensure that data does not get added in the table without a company code. Without making it a part of primary key or a non null field, it is upto program logic to ensure that. In my opinion, DB should also ensure that. Second issue is with the table task id. It is possible for 2 companies to have same employee id's and same task ids. DB should not restrict that.

Comment: any id (Employeeid, CompanyId, TaskId) is a database artifact and is not visible to the user and cannot be manipulated by user in any way.

Comment: Agreed it cannot be manipulated by user. The trouble will happen  when you have new tenants who will use similar ids to existing tenants. Either your application logic has to cover that, or you may start getting wrong results all of a sudden. My suggestion is to ensure at the table level that different tenants data can live without imposing any conditions on that data.

Comment: they would not use the same ids for instance: there are two employees with same name in different companies: **Employee James** for Company A has id 45 but james for Company Z has id 678. User access Employee:James but if he is the user of Company A the id would be 45, but if the user from Company Z it would be 678.

Comment: In multi tenancy, in my opinion, you should not put such restrictions. So James from company A and James from company Z should be allowed to have same Employee id.  Another potential problem could be, your emp ids for one company would not be in sequence. So Company A will have emp id 1, company Z may have 2,3,4 and then next emp of company A will get id of 5. DB should not decide what Ids companies can have and cannot have. However, its a matter of choice. If your application users are fine with having unique ids, then its fine. Same problem will be faced in task id etc.

Comment: Another consideration, as data grows, joins will become slower. That consideration should also favor putting company key in task table.

Comment: Having ids in sequence does not make sense as it does not convey any information by itself. so if id is not an int but a GUID then you cannot even have a sequence. however your point about slower join is important